# Wordpress gravity form update the 'City' dropdown based on the selected 'Country'

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I have 2 select options created on gravity forms

- Country
- City

I want to change the City dropdown based on selected Country

Is that possible in gravity form?

How can I achieve that function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in Gravity Form.

**Here's how:**

1. Create country dropdown

[image]

2. Create another dropdown for city
3. Go to advanced tab and enable conditional logic (will be displayed for UK)

[image]

4. Repeat the step 2 and 3 for second city and so on...

[image]

**Form on frontend:**

**Default:**

[image]

**US Selected:**

[image]

**UK Selected:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I wonder that I have to list all the country in the world with their corresponding cities. What will happen is that their will be so many City dropdowns.  Hmmm..  (thinking)